# Forcing a user to upload an image during registration Django

Tags: django

I've extended my user model with profile, and have made it so that a profile object gets made when user does. Now, I am trying to add my own fields during registration,  description and photo. However, I am having trouble doing that. I'm not sure what I'm getting this error as I feel like I've separated the two models in forms.py, so I'm not sure where the error is coming from.

**Error:**

```
AttributeError at /register/
type object 'Profile' has no attribute 'USERNAME_FIELD'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/register/
Django Version: 3.0.5
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
type object 'Profile' has no attribute 'USERNAME_FIELD'
Exception Location: /Users/papichulo/Documents/DatingApp/11_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py in __init__, line 109
Python Executable:  /Users/papichulo/Documents/DatingApp/11_env/bin/python
Python Version: 3.7.3
Python Path:    
['/Users/papichulo/Documents/DatingApp',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python37.zip',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/papichulo/Documents/DatingApp/11_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
```

**views.py**

```
def register(request):

    form1 = UserForm(prefix="user")
    form2 = ProfileForm(prefix="profile")

    if request.method == "POST":
        form1 = UserForm(request.POST, prefix="user")
        form2 = ProfileForm(request.POST,request.FILES, prefix="profile")

        if form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
            # Save form1 with no commit
            user = form1.save(commit=False) 
            user.username = form1.cleaned_data['username']
            user.email = form1.cleaned_data['email']
            # user.email = form1.cleaned_data['email'] 
            user.save()
            user.profile.user = user
            user.profile.description = form2.cleaned_data['description']
            user.profile.photo = form2.cleaned_data['photo']
            user.profile.save()
            # Some return statement you choose
            return redirect('dating_app:home')
    # ***
    return render(request, 'dating_app/register.html', {"form1": form1, "form2": form2})
```

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from dating_project import settings
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver



class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_photo',blank=False, height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(default="")
    matches = models.ManyToManyField(User,blank=True, related_name='+')

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Profile.objects.create(user=instance)



    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

from dating_app.models import Profile

from dating_app.models import User



class UserForm(UserCreationForm):


    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username","email","password1","password2")

class ProfileForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('photo','description')
```

**register.html**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="{% url 'dating_app:register' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       {% csrf_token %}
       {{form1}}
       {{form2}}
       <br>
       <div class="form-group">
           <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
           </div>
       </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the error kinda explains itself

```
AttributeError at /register/
type object 'Profile' has no attribute 'USERNAME_FIELD'
```

your Profile model has no such attribute. The 'USERNAME_FIELD' is an attribute of User model. UserCreationForm is used only for your "base" User creation and it requires USERNAME_FIELD to be present in its Meta model. Here you have stated all the attributes required to use UserCreationForm:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm

In your Case you should just simply extend forms.ModelForm for Profile instance creation
like this

```
from django.forms import ModelFrom

class ProfileForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('photo','description')
```